# how to create dictionary, from two columns of Dataframe which is list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I Have Dataframe as below,

```
   text       num     w        wei
0  he is good   0   [a, b]   [1, 2]
1  hello        1   [c, b]   [3, 2]
2  here         4   [a, c]   [1, 3]
```

I want to get like this,

```
       text       num     w        wei     dic_w_wei
0  he is good   0     [a, b]     [1, 2]    {"a": 1, "b":2}
1  hello        1     [c, b]     [3, 2]    {"c": 3, "b":2}
2  here         4     [a, c]     [1, 3]    {"a": 1, "c":3}
```

dic_w_wei is new column from above w, and wei. how to get this new columns.

now at end i want dictionary like this from this dataframe,

```
{"a": 2, "b": 4, "c": 6}
```

where , i am summing it all value of a, b and c.

Comment: Can you provide sample df as df.to_dict().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `apply`;

```
df['dic_w_wei'] = df[['w','wei']].apply(lambda x: dict(zip(*x)),axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df)
```

---

```
         text  num       w     wei         dic_w_wei
0  he is good    0  [a, b]  [1, 2]  {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
1       hello    1  [c, b]  [3, 2]  {'c': 3, 'b': 2}
2        here    4  [a, c]  [1, 3]  {'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```

Once we have this column you can do:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['dic_w_wei'].tolist()).sum().astype(int).to_dict()
```

---

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6}
```

Example df below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': {0: 'he is good', 1: 'hello', 2: 'here'},
    'num': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4},
    'w': {0: ['a', 'b'], 1: ['c', 'b'], 2: ['a', 'c']},
    'wei': {0: [1, 2], 1: [3, 2], 2: [1, 3]}})
```

Comment: what about next output, like adding all the value of a, b and c. and get dictioanry format.
{"a": 2, "b": 4, "c": 6}